# Extracting columns from text file using Perl one-liner: similar to Unix cut

Tags: python, perl, unix, batch-file

I'm using Windows, and I would like to extract certain columns from a text file using a Perl, Python, batch etc. one-liner.

On Unix I could do this:

```
cut -d " " -f 1-3 <my file>
```

How can I do this on Windows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a Perl one-liner to print the first 3 whitespace-delimited columns of a file.  This can be run on Windows (or Unix).  Refer to [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

```
perl -ane "print qq(@F[0..2]\n)" file.txt
```

Comment: `perl -pane "$_ = qq(@F[0..2])"`

Answer (score 3):

you can download [GNU windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) and use your normal cut/awk etc..
Or natively, you can use vbscript

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strFile = objArgs(0)
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfLine
    strLine=objFile.ReadLine
    sp = Split(strLine," ")
    s=""
    For i=0 To 2
        s=s&" "&sp(i)       
    Next
    WScript.Echo s
Loop
```

save the above as mysplit.vbs and on command line

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo mysplit.vbs file
```

Or just simple batch

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%a in (file) do (echo %%a %%b %%c)
```

If you want a Python one liner

```
c:\test> type file|python -c "import sys; print [' '.join(i.split()[:3]) for i in sys.stdin.readlines()]"
```

Answer (score 2):

That's rather simple Python script:

```
for line in open("my file"):
    parts = line.split(" ")
    print " ".join(parts[0:3])
```

Comment: print "\n".join(" ".join(line.split(" ") for line in open("my file"))

Ugly one-liner

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it would be to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and use the Unix `cut` command.

Comment: its even easy to download and install GNU win32 tools than cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a text file that has very long lines and you are only interested in the first 3 columns, then splitting a fixed number of times yourself will be a lot faster than using the `-a` option:

`perl -ne "@F = split /\s/, $_, 4; print qq(@F[0..2]\n)" file.txt`

rather than

`perl -ane "print qq(@F[0..2]\n)" file.txt`

This is because the `-a` option will split on every whitespace in a line, which potentially can lead to a lot of extra splitting.